# a4j:commandButton gets invoked when hitting enter

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a span of two components, a search field and a command button. The command button is for a separator task. So when the input field gets focused and the user hits enter, it should redirect to a search result page and the command button shouldn't be invoked.

```
<s:span>
    <h:inputText value="#{search.input}" onkeypress="performSearch(event)"/>
    <a4j:commandButton image="icon.jpg" action="#{some action}" ajaxSingle="true">
    </a4j:commandButton>
</s:span>
```

performSearch is a javascript function which invoke the actual search on Enter.

Now, the action of the commandButton gets invoked when hitting enter on the input field. Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onkeypress` should return `false` when the enter key is been pressed. This will block the default action of the enter key.

Thus so,

```
onkeypress="return performSearch(event)"
```

with something like

```
function performSearch(event) {
    // ...

    if (notEnterPressed) {
        return true;
    }

    // Perform search.
    // ...

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it on Firefox 10 and IE9 and it works. But on the early version of FF, like FF3, and IE7, the problem remains. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: That's specific to `onkeypress` attribute. Use `onkeydown` (or `onkeyup`) instead if you want to support older browsers as well.